# I'm trying to crop the sides of a movie which are unwanted... Online

Tags: video-editor, screen-casting

I am trying to crop my video online, like it's done below. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

[image: What I'm trying to do but this is on a program]

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you specifically want to be able to do it online?  If you are screen casting, why not only capture the area you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BEFORE I would say
onetruemedia.com

It HAD a great online video editor, but that was bought out by disney and then shut down. (Disney just wanted the tools in one of their software bundles)

Currently I would say 
videotoolbox.com
Not the most intuitive, actually a very poor user interface.
But it has the crop feature you are looking for, not easy to find.
But here is a little video on how to use the online tool